# regex, strings - removal of a matching element

Tags: jquery, regex, string, indexing

I have the strings in following formats:

```
apple|mango|banana|pineapple
(or)
mango|banana|pineapple
(or)
banana|pineapple
```

I would like to remove a matching element from this string - like if the matching element is mango.

I need the string as: `apple|banana|pineapple`

if apple:

```
mango|banana|pineapple.
```

How do I do that, should I use a regex, for matching element I need to remove that and pipe before that, here the matching element is dynamic. Please help.

Comment: You just want to remove a variable string from what's matched? Just concatenate the variable in string format to the regex in the appropriate spot. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: You'll probably need some logic on top of the expression, what language are you using?

Comment: I am trying to do this in jquery/js.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string into array, remove the item, and join it again.

```
var s = 'apple|mango|banana|pineapple';
var itemToRemove = 'apple';
var items = s.split('|');
var itemToRemoveIndex = $.inArray(itemToRemove, items);
if (itemToRemoveIndex != -1) {
    items.splice(itemToRemoveIndex, 1);
    s = items.join('|');
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xerA9/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for the `String.split()` Javascript method.

```
var fruit = "apple|mango|banana|pineapple";
var fruitArr = fruit.split("|"); // ["apple","mango","banana","pineapple"]
```

You can then use `Array.indexOf()` and `Array.splice()` methods to remove it. *This will only remove the first instance found, as `indexOf` aborts after finding a match.*

```
fruitArr.splice(fruitArr.indexOf("mango"), 1);
// Returns ["mango"] but fruitArr has been modified to ["apple","banana","pineapple"]
```

`fruitArr`, after being modified with `splice`, can be re-merged like this:

```
fruitArr.join("|"); // "apple|banana|pineapple"
```

See Ulugbek's answer for a more failsafe version of this— but be aware that it depends on jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following a simple replace method:

```
youString.replace(/\|*mango/g, '')
```

The '*' after the '|' will catch mango if it is at the beginning of the string.

Comment: In case of `mango|apple` it generates `|apple`, while it should be `apple`. You can use `\bmango\||\|mango\b` regex, but split/join is simpler, since you don't need to create dynamic regex.

Comment: You are correct on the regex. I forgot about the additional '|' when removing from the beginning.

Comment: I understand that it's not much cleaner using dynamic regex than your split/join approach, however, in case regex is preferred, the following would work: var pattern = "\\b" + strToRemove + "\\||\\|" + strToRemove + "\\b"; var reg = new RegExp(pattern, "g"); str.replace(reg, '');